# Select a single 'featured' post in Tumblr?

Tags: tumblr

I would like my Tumblr homepage to show a single Question/Answer post that is selected by a 'featured' tag, or rather by being the most recent Question/Answer post tagged 'featured'. I don't see any built in Tumblr tags that will do this.

Answer (score 3):

I am using jQuery to get the featured post (n number of them) from a category 'featured' by default. I have implemented this solution to my theme - [Purely](http://purely-theme.tumblr.com/)

Here is a screen-shot (displaying three featured posts)
[image: Screenshot of my blog]
Add this line 's meta section

```
<meta name='text:Featured Tag' content='featured' />
```

Add jQuery library in

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Add these lines in  where you want to display the featured post

```
{block:IndexPage}
 {block:IfFeaturedTag}
   <h1 class="featured-subhead">
     Featured Posts <a href="/tagged/{text:Featured Tag}"> + </a>
   </h1>
 {/block:IfFeaturedTag}
{/block:IndexPage}
```

Add these lines just before the closing  tag

```
{block:IndexPage}{block:IfFeaturedTag}
<script>
    var rssurl = '/tagged/{text:Featured Tag}/rss';
    $.get(rssurl, function(data) {
    $('.featured-subhead').append('<div class="featured-posts">');
    var $xml = $(data);
    var vari = 0;
    $xml.find("item").each(function() {
        var $this = $(this),
            item = {
                title: $this.find("title").text(),
                link: $this.find("link").text(),
                description: $this.find("description").text(),
                pubDate: $this.find("pubDate").text(),
                author: $this.find("author").text()
        }
        vari = vari +1;
        if(vari <4){
        $('.featured-subhead').append('<div class="featured-post" style="overflow:hidden;"><h2 class="featured-title"><a href="' + item.link + '">' + item.title + '</a></h2><div class="featured-post-description' + vari + '">' + item.description + '</div><div class="featured-post-link"><a href="' + item.link + '">Read More</a></div></div>');
        //Do something with item here...
        }
    });
    $('.featured-subhead').append('</div>');
});
{/block:IndexPage}{/block:IfFeaturedTag}
```

You can change if(vari <4){ line according to the numbers of posts you want to display as featured. For example, to display a single post, it would be if(vari <2){ .

I have also added few CSS classes to design the output. This can be declared in  segment in

```
h1.featured-subhead
{
/* Heading of featured post */
}
.featured-posts
{
/* Outer box of all featured posts */
}
.featured-post
{
/* Inner box of each featured post */
}
h2.featured-title
{
/* Heading of each featured post */
}
.featured-post-description
{
/* Description or body of each featured post */
}
.featured-post-link
{
/* Link to Permalink page of each featured post */
}
```

Here only featured-subhead class is necessary. This must be added to the heading of featured post. jQuery will add the featured posts after that.

How does it work?
No surprises here. Tumblr generates a tag RSS page for each page. By using javascript, I am fetching that specific tag page and displaying 'n' number of elements from the XML elements. Sometimes, Tumblr takes a little more time (I don't know why) to generate the RSS page of newly added tags. Be patient and try to browse your-blog.tumblr.com/tagged/featured/rss page to check it is generated or not.

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking is not a native setting to tumblr, in other words there's no preference setting you can simply check.

In order to do what you describes above, you will either need to edit your current theme code, or code a new theme from scratch.

In order to only show 1 question post, at the top, with a tag of featured, you will need to work with the jQuery/Javascript and the Tumblr API.

It's pretty complex coding, but if you're up for it, head on over to the [Tumblr API Codex](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api).

Answer (score 0):

This is a little late, but in case it's of any help: Our free Single A theme has the sticky post feature built in. It's the first (and only) tumblr theme to have it. You can get it here: http://www.tumblr.com/theme/28638 or learn more about it here: http://singleatheme.tumblr.com/. Hope this helps!